# Easy JS variable passing issue

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an XHR call getting a date for me, but can't seem to pass it into the page. I just need to pass the date from the XHR call to a variable to be inserted via `document.write`.

Here is my code:

```
var upDated

function getUpdated(){

xmlhttp.open("HEAD", "MBP_box.JPG",true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
   upDated = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");
   alert(upDated);
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.send(null)
}
```

and in the body....

```
document.write(upDated);
```

Comment: How do you get that date in the XHR call?

Comment: you can get the response headers as shown above. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html for a list of http headers

Comment: This is a better organized ref http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers

Comment: Thanks for the help folks :)

The working code as i needed it is here as a reference;

http://swind.co.uk/_bin/TEST/XHR_TEST

Answer (score 3):

Instead of alert(upDated); you should have something like:

```
document.getElementById("some-element").innerHTML = upDated;
```

The idea is pretty simple, you must keep the logic inside the callback function (the one assigned to onreadystatechange) as you have no idea when it will be called (it will be called when the browser has received some response from the server, which may just as well not happen). So having some code after you set this connection won't work.

Comment: dammit. yes of course.

im mixing old and new. (my JS is very sketchy..)

this makes perfect sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want - do you mean you want the value of upDated, as returned via the Ajax call, to be inserted into the document body via `document.write`?

If so, you definitely can't do this. `document.write` is executed as soon as it is encountered, which will be while the document is loading. If you want to inject a value dynamically, you will have to use a DOM method.

Comment: or use .innerHTML as lonut did. (note that innerHTML is not part of any DOM standard)

Comment: "I'm not sure I understand what you want - do you mean you want the value of upDated, as returned via the Ajax call, to be inserted into the document body via document.write?"

yes exactly that.

i think ive got it. - its my stupid old JS brain.. :)
need to to use a DOM insert instead.